# Installing a command line utility from installing a python package

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python package that relies on a command line utility to work. I am wondering if anyone knows how to make pip install that command line utility when pip installs my package. The only documentation I can seem to find is on dependency_links which looks to be depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set dependencies on another *python* package (e.g. using `install_requires` in your `setup.py`), but if your code relies on a specific non-Python binary you cannot have that installed automatically as part of the `pip install` process.

You could create a native package for your operating system, which would allow you to set dependencies on other system packages such that when your Python script was installed with `apt`/`yum`/`dnf`/etc, the necessary binary would be installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have a look at the pycrypto setup.py script which installs on all sorts of OSs and has dependencies.

In short you need to handle OS versions and install the dependencies with whatever mean is available, mainly the `os.system.cmd(<command>)` to use the os based command line.

if you have source code, then you can also compile it in your install phase.

https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: While you can of course run arbitrary commands in your `setup.py` script, there is no guarantee that you are running as `root` and unless you decide  you're going to write your own os-agnostic package installation tool you're going to be limited to installing packages only on specific distributions or operating systems.